# (?p=home) includes pages not working

Tags: php, configuration

I have setup a new server and copyed my website on to it and the follow dont work (?p=home) includes pages.

Code:

```
 if(isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['p']))
 {
$page = $HTTP_GET_VARS['p'];
}
else
{
$page = 'home';
}

switch($page)
{
         case 'home':
  require('home.php');
  break;
         case 'login':
  require('login.php');
  break;

  default:
  echo('Error: There is no file on this server with that name');
 }
```

On the other webhost it was on it worked fine am think in that it is a php.ini config file need editing can anyone help me?

Comment: And please elaborate on the "(?p=home) includes pages" - maybe it's just me but I have no idea what that means....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`$_GET` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) instead of `$HTTP_GET_VARS`. The latter one is deprecated and probably disabled due to [*register_long_arrays*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

This must do the trick :)

```
if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}
else
{
    $page = 'home';
}
```